# how to create file .exe from javafx project

Tags: java, javafx

Pleased help me, I need build file .exe from javaFX project, I try use launch4j to convert Jar file to file .exe but it isn't working.

[image]

Comment: The error tells you to try running with `--enable-preview`.

Comment: I understand about --enable-preview-- can you help me

Answer (score 0):

You have to run

1. maven build [mvn clean install]
2. ant build [ant]

for generating executable files out of your project.

For that two necessary files are : build.xml and pom.xml.

For creating build.xml file , refer https://ant.apache.org/manual/tutorial-HelloWorldWithAnt.html

Answer (score -2):

in build.fxbuild choose all in packaging format, it will generate .exe file